# split method in java

Tags: java, regex, split

Here is my code to split given string and put them into an array. 
Question, I want it to work while I am passing an empty String. How is that possible?

```
String[] buArray = buList.split(";", -1);
```

So I want `buArray.length` equals zero while passing `""`.

Comment: Not possible with just a split call; all splits of the blank string result in `new String[]{""}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like below:

```java
String[] buArray = 
  (buList == null || buList.isEmpty()) 
  ? new String[0]: buList.split(";");
```

You can remove null check if it is not needed.